# email can't send to email address using actionmailler

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

why i try to send email to my email address using actionmailler is failed?

whats wrong with my code and my config?

config

```
<system.net>
    <mailSettings>
      <smtp deliveryMethod="Network" from="myemail@gmail.com">
        <network host="smtp.gmail.com" userName="myemail@gmail.com" password="fakepass" port="587"/>
      </smtp>
    </mailSettings>
  </system.net>
```

mailler controller

public class MailController : MailerBase
{

```
public EmailResult SampleEmail(EmailModels model)
{
    From = "myemail@gmail.com";
    To.Add(model.Email);
    Subject = "test";
    return Email("SampleEmail",model);
}
```

send email method

```
public ActionResult SendEmail()
        {
            var user = new EmailModels
            {
                FirstName = "send_email",
                Email = "send_email@gmail.com"
            };
            new MailController().SampleEmail(user).DeliverAsync();
            return View();
        }
```

Comment: what happen when you try to send any error?

Comment: What about enabling SSL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write this:

```
<network enableSsl="true" host="smtp.gmail.com" userName="myemail@gmail.com" password="fakepass" port="587"/>
```

In place of:

```
<network host="smtp.gmail.com" userName="myemail@gmail.com" password="fakepass" port="587"/>
```